# PhpStorm is not applying default PHPUnit configuration

Tags: php, automated-tests, phpunit, phpstorm

In PhpStorm (latest, running on Ubuntu 22.04), I have set the default PHPUnit configuration file path, but when I create a new run configuration (such as happens automatically when I run individual tests from within the editor), it does not apply the default configuration but instead needs to have the file specified manually.

To illustrate: I have set default path to `phpunit.xml` here:

[image]

But if I right-click on a test file and attempt to run it, like so:

[image]

The tests do not run, `--no-configuration` is passed to the command line instead of the file path, and I get a message saying that PHPUnit is not configured:

[image]

I can see that it has created a run configuration specially for that test file:

[image]

And I can see that it knows about the default file path, because when I click the gear icon next to "Use alternative configuration file", this pops up:

[image]

However, the default setting is somehow not being applied. I can get it to run by ticking "Use alternative configuration file" and entering exactly the same path as the default one.

[image]

The configuration file path is now passed to the command line and the tests run successfully:

[image]

This is inconvenient because whenever I want to run a new test class I have to manually edit the run configuration. On previous machines I have only had to enter the default configuration and then I could run individual tests without needed to re-enter it.

Comment: You are not alone who is facing this. To avoid specifying the `Use alternative configuration file` for every newly created Run/Debug Configuration manually (the current workaround), just edit the defaults for that Run/Debug Configuration type and it will be applied for every newly created entry from there. Look at the `Edit configuration templates...` link at the bottom left on your Run/Debug Configurations screen (not shown on your screenshots, but it is there).

Comment: Not 100% sure why this happens ... but it sounds like it *may be* related to Php Interpreter used for the project -- Local vs Remote (Docker etc). You may check tickets here, maybe you can find the one that fits your setup. Just go through the top 10-20 results and check the comments/screenshots there.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=phpunit%20default%20configuration

Comment: Most probably it's [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-73715/PHPUnit-configuration-file-from-main-project-isnt-passed-to-PHPUnit-execution-command-for-subproject). It's being tested at the moment, we hope to release the fix with 2023.2.1